# Rendering Issue with Include template tag and forms

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, view

Disclaimer: I am aware of several other posts that raise my issue, but they do not apply to my code.

Hi everyone, I am creating a knockoff of stackoverflow using Django, and I came into an issue.
I have a View that shows a question that has been asked. Obviously, anyone coming to that question should be able to answer it. Here are the views and templates:

This view displays the question and some other info:

```
class QuestionsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "function/questions/questions_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        question_detail = Question.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs.get("pk")).first()
        answers = Answer.objects.filter(question=question_detail)

        context["question"] = question_detail
        context["questioncomments"] = QuestionComment.objects.filter(question=question_detail)
        context["answers"] = [[answer, AnswerComment.objects.filter(answer=answer)] for answer in answers]
        return context
```

This view allows you to answer:

```
class AnswersCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Answer
    fields = ["content"]
    template_name = "function/answers/answers_create.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("function-questions-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.kwargs.get("pk")})
```

On stackoverflow, when you view a question, you can answer it by scrolling down and providing your answer. I wanted to do something similar, so instead of having the answer view on a separate page, I put in in the question detail page using the 'include' template tag. Here are the templates:

This is the template for the question (which contains the include statement (bottom)):

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

    <!--Question-->

    <h1>{{ question.title }} by {{ question.author }}</h1>

    {% if user == question.author %}
        <a href="{% url 'function-questions-update' question.id %}">Update</a>
        <a href="{% url 'function-questions-delete' question.id %}">Delete</a>
    {% endif %}

    <h3>{{ question.content }}</h3>

    <!--QuestionComments-->

    {% for comment in questioncomments %}
        <h6>{{ comment }}  --  {{ comment.author }}</h6>
    {% endfor %}

    <!--Answers-->

    {% if answers %}

        {% for pair in answers %}

            <!--Answers-->

            <h3>{{ pair.0.content }}</h3>
            <h5>{{ pair.0.author }}</h5>

            <!--AnswerComments-->

            {% for comment in pair.1 %}

                <h6>{{ comment }}</h6>

            {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}

    {% include 'function/answers/answers_create.html' %}
  
{% endblock content %}
```

Here is the template for the form which allows you to create an answer (this is the template that is referenced by the include template tag):

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2>Your Answer</h2>
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I tried it out on the website in a browser, the question was rendering but the answer form was rendering everything except the form fields. It is rendering 'Your Answer' and the submit button but it is not rendering the actual field.

When I press submit I get the following error in my command prompt:

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /questions/3/
Method Not Allowed: /questions/3/
```

So, in actual fact, the problem is how do I render the form properly. And will that solve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use form and pass it through context in your DetailView.

```
#form
class AnswerCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      fields = ['content']

#views 
class QuestionsDetailView(DetailView):
    .......
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ......
        context['form'] = AnswerCreateForm()
        return context

# create view 
# provide same template name as the detail view.
class AnswersCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Answer
    form_class = AnswerCreateForm
    template_name = "function/questions/question_detail.html"
```

Comment: The form field has successfully loaded but whenever I click submit, I get the same error: Method Not Allowed (POST): /questions/3/
Method Not Allowed: /questions/3/

Comment: Provide your create view url inside your form action.

Comment: Was that the name of the url?

Comment: What's the url for your create view ?

Comment: I don't have a url for the answer create view. I just want it to redirect to the same page

Comment: You need some url for this view as well and provide this url in your form action